Landscape Sync pocket "Activity" stuck as "Queued"
I'm currently testing out the features of running a standalone air-gapped Landscape server (24.04.5) and have somehow managed to get the Sync pocket 'release' of series 'focal' in distribution 'ubuntu' stuck in a "Queued" state with a status of "1 activity awaiting delivery".
This activity has been 'stuck' for well over a day now so I don't think this is a patience issue.  I am wondering what options I have available to cancel this activity and allow me to continue my testing.
Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.
